# Under what circumstances can a $_SESSION variable be lost across two PHP scripts?

Tags: php

I know it can happen if one is redirecting across sub-domains for example. Are there any other examples of when the SESSION variable is lost in between two PHP scripts?

Comment: It's not session variables that are lost -- simply that the session cookie has not been set to apply across all sub-domains.

Comment: I see....thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

Five come to mind immediately, but there are probably a bunch more:

1. Cookies are disabled.
2. session_start is not called.
3. session_start is called in the wrong place.
4. session_id changes (either the name of the cookie variable or the ID itself)
5. Godzilla and other catastrophic failures.

Comment: Those are most often caused by the programmer. PHP lets you re-assign session ID's and rename the variable. This is really useful if you'd like to do things like obscure the current session ID, but it also has a tendency to break things if it is not tested *very* carefully.